# how to use shredpreferences to store stage of levels

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am creating a game with several levels.
i use integer shared preferences in the resume function and then i put the stage in it.
To put this value in Shared Preference i use following code.

```
 private void resetGame() {

    position = 0;
    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
    editor.putInt("stage", stage);
      editor.commit();   

    String dashes = "";
    switch(stage){
    case 0:
    {
         db.open();
            String st=db.newword(1);
         currentWord = st;
            byte[] p=db.getpic(1);
            Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
            img.setImageBitmap(bm);
            break;

    }
```

and after winning in each level

```
Toast.makeText(Main.this, "You win!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stage++;
            resetGame();
            return;
```

but it dosent work ... i hope you help me thanks alot :)

its the total code i tried all suggestions but didn't work
when i exit the game the level starts from begining

```
public class Main extends Activity {


private String            currentWord;
private TextView          txtDashes;
private ImageView img;
private Button button18;
private database db;
private int      position;
private ArrayList<Button> invisibleButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();

private int               nCorrect;
private int stage;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    txtDashes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDashes);
    Button btnNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNew);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    button18 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Button18);

     db=new database(this);

     db.useable();

     stage= 0;

    btnNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            resetGame();
        }
    });


    position=0;
    resetGame();
}


private void resetGame() {

    position = 0;

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String dashes = "";
    switch(stage){
    case 0:
    {
        stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 0);
         db.open(); 
            String st=db.newword(1);
         currentWord = st;
            byte[] p=db.getpic(1);
            Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
            img.setImageBitmap(bm);
            break;

    }
    case 1:{

        stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 1);
            db.open(); 
            String st=db.newword(2);
         currentWord = st;
            byte[] p=db.getpic(2);
            Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
            img.setImageBitmap(bm);
            break;

    }
    case 2:{

        stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 2);
        db.open();  
        String st=db.newword(3);
         currentWord = st;
        byte[] p=db.getpic(3);
        Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);


        break;

}
    case 3:{

        stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 3);
        db.open();  
        String st=db.newword(4);
         currentWord = st;
        byte[] p=db.getpic(4);
        Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);
        db.close();
        break;

}


    }


    for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.length(); i++) {
        dashes = dashes + "-";

    }

    txtDashes.setText(dashes);
    for (Button btn: invisibleButtons) {
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    invisibleButtons.clear();
    nCorrect = 0;
}




public void letterOnClickListener(View view) {
    Button btn = (Button) view;
    btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    invisibleButtons.add(btn);
    char letter = btn.getText().toString().toCharArray()[0];

        char[] dashesArray = txtDashes.getText().toString().toCharArray();
        char[] charArray = currentWord.toCharArray();

            if (charArray[position] == letter) {
                nCorrect++;
            } 
        dashesArray[position] = letter;
        position ++;

        txtDashes.setText(new String(dashesArray));

        if (nCorrect == currentWord.length()) {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "You win!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stage++;
            resetGame();
            return;
        }
    else {
        if (position >= currentWord.length()) {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "You lose!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            resetGame();
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you pulling the data out of shared preferences?

Comment: Also, since you don't care about the boolean success returned by `editor.commit()` you should use `editor.apply()`. It is async and faster.

Comment: nowhere i just use it for switch case

Comment: i used editor.apply(); but it makes error :(

Comment: Is the issue that the next level doesn't come or that it doesn't restore to the level you were on when you re-open the app

Comment: define `doesn't work`

Comment: it doesn't restore to the level i was on when i re-open the app it starts from the begining ....

Comment: Can you post the method where you get the Previously Stored Stage?

Comment: i dont know how to get Previously Stored  stage woulld you tell me how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass Context through resetGame method

```
     Toast.makeText(Main.this, "You win!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        stage++;
        resetGame(Main.this);
        return;
```

Use SharedPrefs using context only:

```
private void resetGame(Context context){
SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.apply(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you must retrieve the stage from shared preferences.

```
private void resetGame() {

position = 0;
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 0);

String dashes = "";
switch(stage){
case 0:
{
     db.open();
        String st=db.newword(1);
     currentWord = st;
        byte[] p=db.getpic(1);
        Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);
        break;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
    editor.putInt("stage", stage);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: stage = prefs.getInt("stage");   getint makes error to change it to getText()

Comment: Add if that was throwing an error it is probably because that method requires a default value in case the key is not found. I have fixed the code.

Comment: if i write this : stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 0);                                      the game will start from the begining every time :|

Comment: Just realized your `resetGame()` method is starting your game not finishing it. In your `onPause()` method you need to store the data and in your `resetGame()` method you retrieve the data.

Comment: yes i call it ! but it set the stage 0 every time :|

Comment: Not much to go off of there. Add details on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong here `stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 0);` should be before the switch statement not inside.

```
private void resetGame() {

    position = 0;

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String dashes = "";
        stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 0); // <--- move this here

    switch(stage){
    case 0:
    {
        //stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 0);
         db.open(); 
            String st=db.newword(1);
         currentWord = st;
            byte[] p=db.getpic(1);
            Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
            img.setImageBitmap(bm);
            break;

    }
    case 1:{

        //stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 1);
            db.open(); 
            String st=db.newword(2);
         currentWord = st;
            byte[] p=db.getpic(2);
            Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
            img.setImageBitmap(bm);
            break;

    }
    case 2:{

        //stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 2);
        db.open();  
        String st=db.newword(3);
         currentWord = st;
        byte[] p=db.getpic(3);
        Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);


        break;

}
    case 3:{

        //stage = prefs.getInt("stage", 3);
        db.open();  
        String st=db.newword(4);
         currentWord = st;
        byte[] p=db.getpic(4);
        Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(p, 0, p.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);
        db.close();
        break;

}


    }


    for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.length(); i++) {
        dashes = dashes + "-";

    }

    txtDashes.setText(dashes);
    for (Button btn: invisibleButtons) {
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    invisibleButtons.clear();
    nCorrect = 0;
}
```